# Insert SQL statement into column and run that dynamically by calling it in a Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a table which basically has columns:

```
 ID| SQL_Statement|
 1   Update Table_A Set Date=Getdate() where ID>100 and ID<200
 2   Update Table_A Set Date=@date     where ID>1 and ID<20
```

So I insert a set of SQL statements like Update/insert having parameters which I have to pass during Runtime . Now I want to call these statements into  a Stored Proc dynamically and run them by giving in the required values.
The reason I am trying to do this is to keep it dynamic.

Once done all I have to do is keep inserting SQL statements that I want to execute into this table and don't have to change the procedure in anyway.

**EDIT:**

We are dealing with a frequently changing SQL statements, and hence I have to put it in a table so I can just call a particular SQL statement with ID and run that again values. Depending on the result of these statements I update other values.

Comment: Replace the hardcoded values in the strings with parameters and call sp_executesql. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx Beware user input, however.

Comment: You don't need to use dynamic sql here. Just create a procedure with two or three parameters and call it.

Comment: If you go with this dynamic sql approach you can and should use parameters with your dynamic sql. This is critical to avoid sql injection. To me this whole approach of storing queries to run later is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: @SeanLange: Can you tell me one major downside of this kind of practice?

Comment: I can come up one pretty easily, it is difficult to write this code so you end up asking for help because it is overly complicated.

Comment: And even worse is you need to be careful about sql injection. It will take quite a bit of effort to make this type of procedure safe from injection as well as dealing with regular exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute SQL statements saved in a table with T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901934/how-to-execute-sql-statements-saved-in-a-table-with-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a procedure that could do what you have demonstrated.

```
create procedure TableA_Update
(
    @Date datetime
    , @MinID int
    , @MaxID int
) as
    set nocount on

    update Table_A
    set [Date] = @Date
    where ID > @MinID
        AND ID < @MaxID 

GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sean, the thing is I have a very frequently changing statements, so I will have to pick these statements from a Metadata table and run the statements and depending on the output need to change values in other tables. So I will have to keep the SQL as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Storing queries in your database to run later that will include parameters from the user is fraught with peril. You have to add a lot of error handling and sql injection is very serious threat that needs to be dealt with. Why do you need to store these queries like this?

Comment: Hey Sean, Thank you and I agree with effects of this. So basically these are like rules that keep changing and are more than 50 rules and counting. I cannot directly define that in a procedure.

Comment: Ugh that sounds like a real pain to deal with. You will have to resort to dynamic sql.