# T SQL Loop through table of SQL Commands and execute each one

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and have a table (tblSQLScripts) containing a field that stores SQL Commands that execute SP's e.g.

```
Field1
EXEC abc, '1'
EXEC xyz, '2'
EXEC qwe, '3'
```

How do I loop through tblScripts and execute the SQL stored in Field1?

Comment: Personally, this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Storing statements in a table, and then running them blindly, can easily lead to injection attacks.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, appreciate that but this is coming form a 3rd party that I have no control over

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute SQL statements saved in a table with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901934/how-to-execute-sql-statements-saved-in-a-table-with-t-sql)

Comment: @SMor not quite as I need to loop through the table

Comment: @Michael here an example https://rextester.com/FVIY26294

Comment: The second answer in the linked question does just what you want ...

Comment: *" but this is coming form a 3rd party that I have no control over"* if you are implementing this, you have full control over it.

Comment: @Larnu thats great, thanks for your help.